# Remove duplicates from a list that includes subdir

Tags: shell

I have list of files like :

```
dir1/file1
dir1/file2
dir1/file3
dir2/file2 (dup)
dir2/file4
```

I want the file output to be :

```
 dir1/file1
    dir1/file2
    dir1/file3
    dir2/file4
```

embedded system so cant use tools metioned in : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71176/find-duplicate-files

Comment: they are an input text file and an output text file? or you have those `dirx/filex` in file system, and want to remove duped files?? what does this mean: `I have list of files like..... I want the file output to be...`

Comment: the latter, Iam on an embedded system so I dont even have uniq :(. but i have latest bash (with awk)

Comment: What embedded system, and what tools do you have available? Your stackexchange link lists several normal tools `fdupes`, `find`, etc.. of which you have none? What about `diff`? Otherwise, it looks like you will be reading and comparing files line-by-line or char-by-char which is obviously not an acceptable solutions in the shell world (especially for large files)

Comment: find, which, diff is fine, anything that busybox supports :) no fdupes

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the commands available to busybox, if I understand you would like to merge (`mv`) the non-duplicate files contained in `dir2` to `dir1` using only the tools available to busybox, then a *linewise* comparison using `diff -q` would be an efficient solution. (you could also use `cmp` instead in a similar manner, but its byte-wise comparison may be a bit slower).

The comparison will require a brute-force file-by-file comparison to compare and then move the file without having the benefit of arrays. A short shell script that takes `dir1` and `dir2` as the arguments to the script could be implemented as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

[ -d "$1" -a -d "$2" ] || {
    printf "usage:  %s dir1 dir2\n" "$0"
    exit 1
}

## move all files in dir2 that do not match a file in dir1 (linewise)
#  to dir1
for i in "$2"/*; do
    for j in "$1"/*; do
        diff -q "$i" "$j" && isdup=1 || isdup=0
    done
    [ "$isdup" -eq 0 ] && mv "$i" "$1"
done

printf "rm -r %s\n" "$2"
# rm -r "$2"            ## you can uncomment to actually remove dir2
```

**Note:** you can uncomment the actual removal of `dir2` if you choose after you confirm the script operation.

**Test Files/Directories**

```
$ dir1> echo a > file1
$ dir1> echo b > file2
$ dir1> echo c > file3
$ dir2> echo b > file2
$ dir2> echo d > file4

$ ls -l dir1
total 20
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    2 Nov 30 23:48 file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    2 Nov 30 23:48 file2
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    2 Nov 30 23:48 file3

$ ls -l dir2
total 16
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    2 Nov 30 23:48 file2
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    2 Nov 30 23:48 file4
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ sh ../../bbdupes.sh dir1 dir2
Files dir2/file2 and dir1/file1 differ
Files dir2/file2 and dir1/file3 differ
Files dir2/file4 and dir1/file1 differ
Files dir2/file4 and dir1/file2 differ
Files dir2/file4 and dir1/file3 differ
rm -r dir2

$ ls -l dir1
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    2 Nov 30 23:48 file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    2 Nov 30 23:48 file2
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    2 Nov 30 23:48 file3
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    2 Nov 30 23:48 file4
```

**Note:** to suppress default output showing file differ, add `>/dev/null 2>&1` following the `diff -q` command.

Let me know if you have further questions.